# invoke-sqlcmd followed by get-childitem doesn't output properly

Tags: powershell

Anybody have an explanation for this?  I've boiled the problem down to a very simply example, two line script in powershell (Note, it has to be in a script or in a function; if you just type these two lines in the editor, it won't reproduce the problem)

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select 'hello world' as Greeting"
get-childitem "c:\"
```

If you run this, the second line seems to output only blank lines.  It's strange.  If you rem out the invoke-sqlcmd, then the result is as expected.  It's as though the invoke-sqlcmd "breaks" the get-childitem.  Any clue what's going on here?

Comment: Is it still broken if you add " | Out-Default" to the of the second line?